# Removed dbus from raspbian

Tags: raspbian, linux, operating-systems, dbus, terminal

I have accidentally removed my dbus file on my Raspberry Pi 3 Raspbian OS
( full Operating system version) (not raspbian lite). I used the command `apt-get remove dbus` to do this uninstall of dbus.

After the removal nearly finished (Did not completly finish), about 90% done, the Pi froze so I restarted then it only allowed a terminal on launch. How do I fix this? what commands can I use on the termanal?

This is what I tried to do so far to restore the raspbian OS:
 (`sudo bash` was to use root in subsequent commands):

---

```
sudo bash
```

---

```
apt-get install --reinstall dbus
```

---

```
apt-get install dbus
```

---

```
apt-get purge dbus
```

---

```
apt-get install dbus
```

---

All the above attempts where entirely unsuccessful and one command even caused a reboot loop for about a hour, untell I pulled the plug on it again.

What other options are there available for me to use? What did I miss?
I did some research prior to posting this question, and found that i eather have to reflash image or reinstall desktop interface. How do i do this? I dont want to reflash. Is this my only option?

Comment: Hopefully someone learnt a lesson or two from this.

Comment: @goldilocks what do you mean?

Comment: Do not "accidently" uninstall things unless you understand what they are for.  While you might be able to put a linux system together without dbus, it is critical to most contemporary distros (you must have gone to some lengths to get it to uninstall).

Comment: @goldilocks yep I learned my lesson there I did it because I needed space so I uninstalled random stuff

Comment: @goldilocks All I did to uninstall by the way was apt-get remove dbus and then type y and enter maybe because I was in root with sudo bash?

Comment: dbus is crapware, +1 to OP

Comment: agreed on that @user2497

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing your dbus would have removed most of your installed packages, so I think you would be running a very bare system. I would re-burn an image, but I guess you could try an install a desktop xserver back on it, most likely have to many errors though.

## Install desktop on Raspberry Pi

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg

sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xinit

sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods

sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends raspberrypi-ui-mods lxterminal gvfs

sudo apt-get install rc-gui
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this! This is what I tried once, but i think I did install Debian-desktop not this one thank you again!

Comment: wow no errors, awesome!